# lighttpd VS Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, lighttpd

could you pelase tell me what's the difference (i never heard of lighttpd before) ? 
pro / cons ?

and what would you pick for a website who have to deal with a lot of querys (like 20,000 min per day) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends what you want to do and what resources you have. But unless you have a very heavy traffic (which you do not have, 20k/day is fairly light) or very complex/dynamic pages that require a lot of server processing, just pick a server with the required features. Apache is a safe bet, in my opinion, and it is not slow, as it is often implied.

Just as a reference, one web site I manage runs apache on an old dual CPU/2G ram and serves 1+ M files per day w/o breaking a sweat (mostly images -- dynamic pages run on app server).

Comment: (celeron 2ghz + 2g ddr). Thanks for your time

Comment: Also, if you have dynamic pages with a database, chances are that that will be your bottleneck, not the web server.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't need any plugins which are only available for apache, lighttpd is usually a better choice when performance is an issue.

Comment: Ah :D so i've one for apache , and another for lighttpd :p